# How do I write a PHP page to bring in variables and display them on the next page?

Tags: php

I am writing a basic PHP web page.  I need the first page to ask for a name and email address.  Then the welcome.php page should display after the Submit button.  It should also display the user's input.  The global variables do not survive after the user clicks submit.  So the welcome.php page is not doing what I want it to do.

Here is the first PHP file (hello.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<?php

$_SESSION["name"] = $name;
$_SESSION["email"] = $email;


?>
```

Here is my welcome.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<?php
session_start();
echo "Your name is " . $_SESSION["name"] . ".<br>";
echo "Your email is " . $_SESSION["email"] . ".";
echo $name
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
```

How do I get the welcome.php page to display the variable $name and $email rather than this:

> Your name is . 
>   Your email is .

I want the name and email to be displayed in those respective lines of output on welcome.php.  What do I do?

Comment: Did you try a search on [Google](http://google.com) and on [PHP.net](http://php.net), if not please do so, if yes, please try to perform a new search. Search for session cookies and related terms.. there are a lot of examples that might be interesting to you

Answer (score 0):

You can get `name` and `email` in post parameters because you have mentioned form action to `welcome.php` file.

```
echo "Your name is " . $_POST["name"] . ".<br>";
echo "Your email is " . $_POST["email"] . ".";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use session to get name and email. You submit data using form with method post. So you need to be get data using POST (superglobal variables)

```
$name=$_POST["name"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
```

Now you can do everything with those whatever you want :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$_SESSION["name"] = $_POST["name"];
$_SESSION["email"] = $_POST["email"];
}
?>
```